# Can we write a script to restart MySQL every time the website is down?

Tags: mysql, shell, amazon-web-services, xampp, lampp

I am using a Linux server hosted on AWS and due to less amount of RAM available the website goes down and I get a "Error establishing connection to database" error.

I have to restart MySQL everytime this happens.

Can we automate this process?

The command I use to restart the LAMPP server is:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Comment: You will need a script that checks every x minutes if the server is up, you wil always end up with a bit of a gap (time between checks). The Process could still be running yet you can't connect. Checking it every 10 seconds doesn't seem like a good plan (at all). You also risk other issues, i would opt for more memory. Don't fix it with scripting... go with a bigger instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bash script to monitor the mysql port and restart it if it is down

Just to demo how it works

The nc command checks that port 3306 (mysql port) is contactable
If it is then $? is set to zero, so this counts as "up"
otherwise $? is down.  You may wish to use a different command instead of "nc", for example `echo "select 1;" | mysql` to attempt to run a do nothing mysql command

```
while [ 1 ]
  do sleep 1
  nc -z localhost 3306
  if [ $? == 0 ]; then echo "up"
  else echo "down"
  fi
done
```

The actual version you might use could look like this

```
while [ 1 ]
  do sleep 10
  nc -vz localhost 3306
  if [ $? != 0 ]; then /opt/lampp/lampp restart
  fi
done
```

You can leave a window open (maybe using the "screens" command too) and run this 24x7

If you can increase the time interval to 1 minute then it would be ok to run out of cron like this

in crontab ( to run every minute)

```
* * * * * /path/to/script
```

script

```
#!/bin/bash
  nc -vz localhost 3306 > /dev/null 2>&1 
  if [ $? != 0 ]; then /opt/lampp/lampp restart
  fi
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS EC2 offers IOPs bursts, so I configure my Linux servers with a large SWAP / Cache . I understand that this is counter to the InnoDB concept that MySQL like to have it all in memory. Additionally you should extend the Memory useage of PHP, assuming that you are using LAMP.

http://charmingwebdesign.com/how-to-add-swap-partition-on-ec2-linux-instance/

http://charmingwebdesign.com/wordpress-support-plugin-woocommerce-excelling-ecommerce-what-is-ideal-php-memory-for-woocommerce/